# Mongoose: condition $or with return separate

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I'm using the mongoose for get the values in the DB that can corresponds with two conditions using $or.
I'm want that the response be separated by the filter.

```
Cars.find({$or : [{color: 'blue'}, {color: 'red'}]}, function(Cars){
   console.log(Cars);
})
```

this code will return:

```
[
 {
   _id: 'Car1',
   color: 'blue'
 },
 {
   _id: 'Car2',
   color: 'red'
 },
]
```

Do you have any way of knowing which objects correspond to each condition? without realize direct comparisons in the objects.

like this:

```
[
  [ //Array with objects with color = 'blue'
    {
      _id: 'Car1',
      color: 'blue'
    },
  ],
  [ //Array with objects with color = 'red'
    {
      _id: 'Car2',
      color: 'red'
    },
  ],
]
```

Comment: can you show your `CArSchema`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can try with `aggregate` query

```
Cars.aggregate([
    {$match:{color:{$in:['red','blue']}}},
    {$group:{_id:"$color",result: { $push: "$$ROOT" }}},
    {$project:{result:1,_id:0}}
    ], function(err, cars){
       if(err) {
          console.log(err);
          // return error
       }
       console.log(cars);
       // return success data
});
```

your output will be like:

```
[
  {
    "result" : [ 
        {
            "_id" : "Car1",
            "color" : "blue"
        }, 
        {
            "_id" : "Car3",
            "color" : "blue"
        }
    ]
 },
 {
    "result" : [ 
        {
            "_id" : "Car2",
            "color" : "red"
        }
    ]
 }
]
```

Answer (score 0):

These are two separate queries, so you can just do them separately and then combine the result. Performance wise it wouldn't be so bad, if your working set fits in the memory and they are indexed:

```
const colors = [{color: 'blue'}, {color: 'red'}];
Promise.all(colors.map(color => Cars.find({ color }).then()))
  .then(result => {
    console.log('This is what you wanted:', result);
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use `$group` `aggregate` operator for this.

```
Cars.aggregate(
    [
        { $group : { _id : "$color", cars: { $push: "$$root" } } }
    ]
);
```

This will give `result` something like this:

```
{
  "_id" : "red",
  "cars" ://array of red color cars
     [
       { "_id" : "car2", "color" : "red"},//if other fields are present, that too
       { "_id" : "car4", "color" : "red" }//...and so on
     ]
}

{
  "_id" : "blue",
  "cars" ://array of blue color cars
     [
       { "_id" : "car1", "color" : "blue"},
       { "_id" : "car2", "color" : "blue" }//...and so on
     ]
}
```

For more information on `$group`, please read [MongoDB $group(aggregation) Documenatation](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/group/).